# How to have multiple align points

Tags: align

How can I achieve multiple align points as illustrated in the picture?

[image]

The corresponding latex code:

```latex
\begin{align*}
    \int_{}^{} \sin\left(x\right) \sin\left(x\right) \mathrm{d}x 
    =&-\sin\left(x\right) \cos\left(x\right) + \int_{}^{} \cos\left(x\right) ^{2} \mathrm{d}x 
    \\[10pt]
    =&-\sin\left(x\right) \cos\left(x\right) +\int_{}^{} \left( 1-\sin\left(x\right) ^{2} \right) \mathrm{d}x 
    \\[10pt]
    =&-\sin\left(x\right) \cos\left(x\right)  + \int_{}^{} 1 \ \mathrm{d}x - \int_{}^{} \sin\left(x\right) 
    ^{2}\mathrm{d}x 
    \\[10pt]
    \iff &\int_{}^{} \sin\left(x\right) ^{2}= \frac{-\sin\left(x\right) \cos\left(x\right) +x}
\end{align*}
```

**Edit:** I don't want to use `\phantom{...}` to align anything. Also, the integral signs should line up in the first and last line.

Comment: If I understand your request correctly, it is sufficient to place the alignment character `&` at the equal sign in each line.

Comment: @AndréC no, the picture is probably not perfect. I want the hole last line be moved where the arrow points (i.e. aligned with the beginning of the first line, so that the integral signs lign up).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I revised the answer to show the results of two different approaches to the alignment issue.]

If you prefer to align the integral symbols in the first and final  rows, you may do so by encasing the first three rows in an interior `aligned` environment, and then align those three rows on their respective `=` symbols.  You should also change all instances of `=&` to `&=` and fix a few further issues (such as supply the missing denominator term in the `\frac` expression in the final row), drop the `_{}^{}` "suffix" from all `\int` directives, and replace all instances of `\left(x\right)` with just `x` in order to cut down on the visual clutter.

Speaking for myself, I believe the whole expression would look just as good, and maybe even better [!], if all four rows were aligned on their `=` symbols. This may be achieved with the use of a single `align*` environment; see the lower half of the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' and 'aligned' environments
\begin{document}

% alignment on the \int symbols in rows 1 and 4:
\begin{align*}
&\begin{aligned}
\int \sin x \sin x \,\mathrm{d}x 
    &= -\sin x \cos x + \int \cos^2 x \,\mathrm{d}x       \\
    &= -\sin x \cos x +\int ( 1-\sin^2 x ) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
    &= -\sin x \cos x  + \int 1 \,\mathrm{d}x 
               - \int \sin^2 x \,\mathrm{d}x 
\end{aligned} \\[\jot]
\iff & {\int} \sin^2 x \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{-\sin x \cos x +x}{2}
\end{align*}

\bigskip
% alignment of the `=` symbols in all 4 rows:
\begin{align*}
\int \sin x \sin x \,\mathrm{d}x 
    &= -\sin x \cos x + \int \cos^2 x \,\mathrm{d}x       \\
    &= -\sin x \cos x +\int ( 1-\sin^2 x ) \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
    &= -\sin x \cos x  + \int 1 \,\mathrm{d}x 
               - \int \sin^2 x \,\mathrm{d}x  \\[\jot]
\iff \int \sin^2 x \,\mathrm{d}x
    &= \frac{-\sin x \cos x +x}{2}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it was not completely clear in my question, but I want the integral sign to sign up, i.e the `\iff` should come before the integral sign of the first line

Comment: but the integral signs still don't line up

Comment: thanks a lot, this is very helpful! Also, could you explain me what exactly `\\[\jot]` does?

Comment: @Kaisan - Please see the latest update to the answer for an approach that assures alignment on the integral symbols. Note that I removed all `[10pt]` vertical spacers. `\\[\jot]` inserts about 5pt of vertical whitespace; to me, that seems about the right amount to visually offset the final row from the first three rows.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need multiple alignment points. I'd avoid the `\Longleftrightarrow` symbol that doesn't really explain anything and use one more step.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d} % or \mathrm{d}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\int \sin^2x \diff x
  &= \int \sin x \sin x \diff x \\
  &= -\sin x\cos x + \int \cos x\cos x \diff x \\
  &= -\sin x\cos x + \int (1-\sin^2x) \diff x \\
  &= -\sin x\cos x + \int 1\diff x - \int \sin^2x \diff x \\
\intertext{Comparing the start and end point,}
\int \sin^2x \diff x &= \frac{x-\sin x\cos x}{2} + c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Change `d` into `\mathrm{d}` if you really prefer an upright ”d” (sorry, I don't). Anyway, using a command for it helps in various ways:

1. you don't need to remember adding `\,`
2. typing `\mathrm{d}` all the times is heavy
3. if you want to change the appearance of the symbol, you just change a single line of code

If you want to omit the `+c`, no problem (I also usually omit it).

Instead of `\intertext{...}` you might put `\Longleftrightarrow` in front of the last integral.

[image]

I'd have no doubt on which to prefer: some words in proof always help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want the last line to have the integral aligned with the integral on the first line and the `=` to be unaligned.

To do this, you'll need to set up the alignment manually using `array`.

```
\[
  \begin{array}
    {
      r@{\;} % ❶
      r@{\;} % ❶
      l
    }
    &\int_{}^{} \sin\left(x\right) \sin\left(x\right) \mathrm{d}x 
       &=-\sin\left(x\right) \cos\left(x\right) + \int_{}^{} \cos\left(x\right) ^{2} \mathrm{d}x 
         \\[10pt]
    &&=-\sin\left(x\right) \cos\left(x\right) +\int_{}^{} \left( 1-\sin\left(x\right) ^{2} \right) \mathrm{d}x 
         \\[10pt]
    &&=-\sin\left(x\right) \cos\left(x\right)  + \int_{}^{} 1 \ \mathrm{d}x - \int_{}^{} \sin\left(x\right) 
    ^{2}\mathrm{d}x 
         \\[10pt]
    \iff &
      \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{ % ❷
         \int_{}^{} \sin\left(x\right) ^{2}= \frac{-\sin\left(x\right) \cos\left(x\right) +x}{2}
      }
  \end{array}
\]
```

We put `@{\;}` between columns to get relation spacing before the alignment points. We also need to add `@{}` before the `l` in the `\multicolumn` ❷ so that we don't get extra inter-column space inserted before the math that will be output there.